# Where to download unix command?

Tags: linux, command-line, ubuntu-10.04

I tried to run

```
% mvdir
```

earlier and it said `command not found`. I then ran a search for it and still not found. Is there a place I can download the script for the command, and is there any information I should know post-download to get it to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Linux does not need `mvdir`. GNU `mv` operates on both files and directories.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the [mv](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv) command for Linux/Ubuntu, assuming you are trying to move a file/directory. mvdir is obsolete.

Comment: what does *"mv is obsolete"* mean?

Comment: I'd assume that it's a typo, and that he meant 'mvdir is obsolete'

Answer (score 1):

If you are accustomed to using 'mvdir' to move folders just assign an alias to it.

```
alias mvdir='mv'
```

Now, 'mvdir' acts the same as typing 'mv'

Comment: This is more of a 'if you're already used to one way, why learn another' type answer.

Comment: Yes... and if you accidentally move a file instead, you'd expect a command like "mvdir" to error out instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple reference pages of Linux commands:

http://ss64.com/bash/

or

http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/